# Rich Image Field rendered as HTML in publishing page - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, publishing, web-controls

I have used SharePoint's Rich Image Field in my page layout. When I traverse into edit mode of the publishing page and add an image in the image field, the image is rendered fine.

But, once I 'Check In' my page using the publishing console and publish the page, the html markup of the image is rendered. How could this be resolved?

Regards,
Raghuraman.V

Comment: Can you please post the html around the field, that's where I think the problem is, not the field itself...

Comment: <td>
<div>
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField ID="ImageField1" FieldName="ImageColumn1" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
</div>                            
</td>

Comment: I have tried wrapping the field inside a div and without the div. It is not working in either circumstances

Answer (score 2):

It might be an issue with your custom Field definition.
Make sure you have something like:

```
<Field
     ID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
     Name="ImageTop"
     DisplayName="Image on Top"
     Type="Image"
     Format="Image"     
     RichText="TRUE"
     RichTextMode="FullHtml"
     Group="My Page Layout Columns">  
  </Field>
```

Comment: For me, it was the RichText="FALSE" that was causing this issue. Changing it to TRUE has made it work well.